# Why does NSDate() store a strange value in CoreData

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am using NSDate() to store now date into CoreData:

```
    sampleSwim.date = NSDate()
```

where sampleSwim is an NSManagedObject backed by a class auto generated from xcdatamodeld file.  In that model date is a Date type.  In the NSManagedObject class it shows up as NSDate.

For some reason Im getting back this value:

```
2014-10-297 05:07:57
```

Ive got quite a few samples of that already.  This is from the console.  Why would this happen?

This is how Im logging it (and reading it):

```
var myWorkout: Swim = self.workouts[indexPath!.row] as Swim
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myWorkout.date as NSDate)
println(date)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this format:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss"
```

- `DD` is "Day of year"
- `hh` is 12 hours format
- `YYYY` is "Week of Year" based.

Here is the document: [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Thanks, is this new?  I don't think I have ever seen that format before.

Comment: I don't think so. Similar one is used in this apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7